# Extra space at left and right of form element in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for registration form but there is extra space at left and right of form field which I want to remove and I need border to start just after the form input field ends.

```
**HTML** **Bootstrap**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bootstrap 3 Registration Form with Validation</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> </head>
<style>
  .container {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form" onsubmit="return FormValidation();">
      <fieldset>
        <!-- Form Name -->

        <center>
          <h2><b>Registration Form</b></h2>
        </center>

        <br>
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
              <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Success message -->
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon
glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Success!.</div>
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-4"><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon
glyphicon-send"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[I want the border asdescribed in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv217.png)

Updated snippet

> .container {            border:1px solid black;         }       .fieldset {
>   padding: 0px; }
>
> ```
>               <center>
>                  <h2><b>Registration Form</b></h2>
>               </center>
>
>            <br>
>            <!-- Text input-->
>            <div class="form-group">
>               <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
>               <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
>                  <div class="input-group">
>                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
>                     <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" class="form-control"  type="text">
>                  </div>
>               </div>
>            </div>
> ```

Comment: Dude, your code is screwed up. Do you mind adding it correctly? Showing a snippet would be awesome... `:)`

Comment: Do you mean "border" or "center on page"  please clarify as the image is not descriptive enough

Comment: #Mark
I mean the the form should be inside small box instead of large box.The position of page is good enough respective of page but my requirement is to reduce the blank space between the border of container and end of text input form element.The width of form container box border should be equal to textinput+First name.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss
I mean the the form should be inside small box instead of large box.The position of page is good enough respective of page but my requirement is to reduce the blank space between the border of container and end of text input form element.The width of form container box border should be equal to textinput+First name.

Comment: @PraveenKumar

Added snippet

Comment: @RavindraSolanki Added answer bro.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first of all, your way of adding the classes is wrong. You should have this structure:

- Container

  - Row

    - Column

It's not there in your way. So, just replace your code with this. Also, you don't do borders for `.container`, but for `form`:

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action=" " method="post" id="contact_form" onsubmit="return FormValidation();">
        <fieldset>
          <!-- Form Name -->
          <h2 class="text-center">Registration Form</h2>
          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Success message -->
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon
glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Success!.</div>
          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4"><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon
  glyphicon-send"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Notes:**

- You don't need `<b>` for `<hX>` tags.
- `<center>` is deprecated, use `class="text-center"`.
- Added the border to `form` instead of `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
fieldset { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Then it is most likely due to specificity. Can you post the CSS for the fieldset from the browser?